# AsyncEventFilterBuilder.deploy raises "Invalid web3 argument" when provided with AsyncWeb3 instance

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, valueerror, web3py

Providing an instance of AsyncWeb3 to async event builder

```
AsyncEventFilterBuilder.deploy(AsyncWeb3)
```

raises `ValueError: Invalid web3 argument: got: <web3.main.AsyncWeb3 object at ...`
It comes from _utils.events:L450, where there is a check `if not isinstance(async_w3, web3.Web3):`. Shouldn't it check for web3.AsyncWeb3 instead?

Providing non-async instance of `Web3` leads to other coroutine related issues. Changing the check to its negation `if isinstance(async_w3, web3.Web3):` delivers expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug has been reported and solved in v6.3.0 https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/2931